# How to get the RTMP & stream name from this URL?

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, rtmp

I am trying to get the RTMP & stream name of the top JW PLAYER that shows up When you open this link: [LINK](http://www.cvinetwork.tv/cv/channel/msnbc4.php)

I have tried everything but I am unable to get it, can someone please help me with this.

My ultimate goal is to be able to grab that stream and put it in my own JWPLAYER,

thank you so much!

any info would really help guys

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your above stream link is http://fw01.livem3u8.me.totiptv.com/live//7f2989e3f87e4efdb36bac56b64dca62.m3u8?bitrate=800

That is working fine right now in VLC player. But for me it was total hit and trail.
What i did for this is I'm going to explain.

1. Download URL Helper from www.urlhelper.com/download.htm (trail version will work fine)
2. Install it and run it.
3. Click Options >> Select and select your network adapter.
4. Click OK.
5. Then click Start at toolbar (It starts watching your network traffic).
6. Run the page where stream is.
7. In a moment URL helper will start showing you some URLs.
8. On the bottom click "All" See here http://s22.postimg.org/9w61m07y9/Untitled.png
9. Copy the URL that is NOT shown as mp3.
10. If you are running only one stream there will be only one address shown multiple times.
11. Copy that URL. That's your stream link. That you can use to run on any player(Hopefully).!

I hope this will work for you as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining how to find this info next time. i really appreciate it

Comment: Downloadhelper is good for this. Firebug also works. For other streams, StreamTransport works as well.