# What is the radio stream url?

Tags: streaming, jwplayer, playlist, turkish

Back from holidays I'm trying to find out the stream url of [TRT Türkü](http://www.trt.net.tr/anasayfa/canli.aspx?y=radyo&k=trtturku) to be able to play it on my mobile device, also when its not in an open tab.

Normally I can locate a playlist xml, but not here?

Comment: I saw there's also a html5-player, doesnt that provide some handles?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18038570/how-to-get-the-rtmp-stream-name-from-this-url

Answer (score 0):

Found it: http://trtcanlifm-lh.akamaihd.net/i/TRTTURKU_1@182246/master.m3u8

(it was in the source of another [page](http://radyo.trt.net.tr/Kanal/5/trt-turku.aspx))